# Request Submission for Public Feed API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our organization is developing a tool for the comment analysis, analyzing that descriptions comments are good or bad, so we need public comment data from Facebook Public Feed API.
I couldn't find any link to raise a request? Am i missing something ? Where should i raise the request for getting the required permissions ?

Comment: It says right on top of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/, _“You cannot apply to use the API at this time.”_ - what part of that is unclear?

Comment: Not clear whether the option to apply for a new media publisher is still available or not ?

Comment: I don’t think there is an actual application process, but rather that this depends on “knowing the right people.”